# Did Thanos use all the powers he had in the film?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Throughout the film we see Thanos use various powers he gains from

> collecting the Infinity Stones.

For example:

> - The Space Stone to warp from location to location 
>  - The Power Stone to torture Thor 
>  - The Reality Stone to trick the Guardian of the Galaxy and Gamora in that he had been killed 
>  - The Time Stone to reverse the destruction of the Mind Stone 
>  - Combining the Space and Power Stones to throw fragment of a moon at Tony, Peter, Strange and the Guardians

but aside from the

> "wipe out half of life in the universe" power he used at the end,

did Thanos ever use any power related to the

> Soul or Mind Stones?

Comment: Well the mind stone was the end piece permitting him to click his fingers. the soulstone however...

Comment: Difficult to say, but he did shrug off the entire Avengers and Wakandans with relative ease once he arrived. His actions also seemed to have different coloured hues around him.

Answer (score 17):

Having seen the movie twice, I can certainly confirm that

> the Soul Stone was used to animate the rock fragments on Titan that became bat-like creatures that were "thrown" (better, *directed*) to Iron Man. If you watch closely, Soul Stone enlightens and moments later you can hear the rustles of the animated "creatures" flying to Tony.

As for

> the Mind Stone,

we can *assume* that it was used to

> gain knowledge on how to heal the wound Thor caused using the Stormbreaker, as Thanos is seen unharmed at the end of Infinity War, when he stares at the sunset. Unless Thanos possesses healing powers, no other Stone -except maybe for the Time Stone- can heal someone, albeit indirectly.

Moreover,

> all six Stones combined were used to wipe out 50% of all life on the universe. So, even if my previous assumption is wrong, Mind Stone was used alongside the other five Stones, for Thanos's greater plan.

Comment: He could've used the time stone to heal his wounds as it also looked like his armor was also restored.

Comment: We do know that the time stone has the power to heal wounds - Doctor Strange's entire motivation for learning sorcery was to heal his hands, and one of the big plot points of Dr. Strange is that he has researched the spell to do it.

Comment: I don't think he ever used the Time Stone to heal his hands, though - he just learned the sorcery necessary to get around the physical damage. In Infinity War, the surgery scars are still visible (if he'd completely reversed the damage I'd expect him to remove those too).

Comment: @Virusbomb agreed, I made some changes to my answer but I should note that regarding the use of the Mind Stone this was an assumption all along.

Answer (score 1):

Soul Stone grants its wielder dominion over life and death, giving the wielder the divine right to decide who lives and who dies. 
**It can also be used to see into a person's soul, with Thanos using it to catch the real Doctor Strange after he had duplicated himself due to his soul.**

The mind stone only be used by Thanos through Loki when he gave Loki that scepter to control other minds. Thanos is already to be said to have a superhuman power as we all witnessed. He is able to heal himself from all of those injuries without needing the mind stone. 
**Although, the mind stone made him able to read minds. Could be why he told Thor that he should have aim the head, because he knows a Stormbreaker that can cut through anything.** Stormbreaker did leave him severely injured, which is not enough to kill him through the chest.

Comment: _"a Stormbreaker that can cut through anything"_ There is only one Stormbreaker. Also, what makes you think it can cut through anything?